# grails 4.x: Creating a WAR with a custom env always runs under development

Tags: java, grails, grails-4

I can't get my custom environment to run under Tomcat. It always loads the development profile.

I create a WAR with the following under Grails 4.0.5:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=qa war
```

The resulting grails.build.info looks correct:

```
info.app.version=2.0.7
info.app.name=myapp
grails.env=qa
info.app.grailsVersion=4.0.5
```

However, when I drop it into Tomcat 8 and run, I get this:

```
 [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.ApplicationLoader        : The following profiles are active: development
```

Running standalone, though, works just fine:

```
./gradlew -Dgrails.env=qa bootRun
```

Answer (score 5):

[grails.util.Environment](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.5/api/grails/util/Environment.html), defines a number of pre-configured environments.

```
Environment APPLICATION
Environment CUSTOM
Environment DEVELOPMENT
Environment PRODUCTION
Environment TEST
```

In `application.yml` we get pre-configured `development`, `test`, and `production` environments. So if we want to add custom environments we add similarly. In your case it will be `qa`.

With Grails command line we can execute any command within the context of a specific environment. The format is:

```
grails [environment] [command name]
```

Suppose if want to create a WAR for the `test` environment you wound run:

```
grails test war
```

To target other environments you can pass a grails.env variable to any command:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=UAT run-app
```

> I create a WAR with the following under Grails 4.0.5:
>
> grails -Dgrails.env=qa war

Yes, all looks good as per grails documentation and configuration.

I have Created POC app for same with `Grails 4.0.5` and also downloaded external tomcat `apache-tomcat-8.5.63`.

[image: Tomcat and grails]

**My `application.yml` with `qa` ENV:**

[image: qa env]

> Running standalone, though, works just fine:
>
> ./gradlew -Dgrails.env=qa bootRun

Yes. This also works fine.
So, now i have created war file with `grails -Dgrails.env=qa war`
Then i started my tomcat and dropped my `poc-app-0.1.war` file into tomcat.

[image]

when tomcat deployed/extracted my war, entered local url into browser.

[image]

You can see in above image, Environment is `qa`

So everything is running as i passed to env while creating war.

I tested with multiple environments, both pre-configured and custom environments. But did not got any issue like created war for `qa` and running on `dev`.

Also i have tested with `java -jar poc-app-0.1.war` and it's running on same env as we given.

Application details:
[image: app details]

and tomcat version is `apache-tomcat-8.5.63`

It may be some versions or configuration issue with your app.

Please refer [this link](https://github.com/rahulmahadik/poc) of my poc. Can you please try to create war and deploy in same way to your tomcat and let me know.

If you are still getting issue, then please share your minimal code or poc.

Even i got one more similar kind of issue on grails repo, please do [refer](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10569) this.

I have followed lot of documentation and references but still not able to reproduce your issue.

Links:

- [Environment class](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/Environment.java)
- [Upgrade Doc](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html)
- [Command Line](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html)
- [API Doc](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.5/api/grails/util/Environment.html)
- [Conf Doc](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.2/guide/conf.html)